# how to deal with an answer that is resolved, but not answered?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, questions

For example, if the problem was resolved without answering the question, how do you deal with the question so that it doesn't remain opened.

Perhaps a device was replaced, or a different software was used in the end, and the question is now meaningless, yet the problem resolved.

Here's [an example](https://superuser.com/questions/189963/linux-network-speed-is-abysmally-slow-while-winxp-is-ok-why) on superuser. Here's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447359/how-to-dynamically-compile-and-load-a-java-class-that-complies-to-an-interface-at) on stackoverflow, where the problem was in the question itself. How do you deal with those kind of questions? leaving them opened seems the wrong thing to do...

Answer (score 6):

If it was resolved, write your own answer and mark it as the valid answer!

Comment: even if the resolution is a side channel thing, like replacing the platform, or finding a problem in the question itself?

Comment: It is up to you - a solution is a solution and you can always write something along the lines of "If anyone has a better answer, please write it", then you can mark it as an answer later if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In [this case](https://superuser.com/questions/189963/linux-network-speed-is-abysmally-slow-while-winxp-is-ok-why) you can post the resolution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

If you had to get it replaced, probably vote to close the question.

Comment: (if you have 250 rep)