# Super Contest Winners: Week 4

Tags: discussion, super-contest

This post is to document the **week 4** winners of the [Super User Super Contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/), for the week ending **Monday, September 13**.

Congratulations to our winners this week!

1. [Best rookie](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-09-13) performance by [**Linker3000**](https://superuser.com/users/49199/linker3000)
2. [Highest reputation](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-09-13) produced by [**Wil**](https://superuser.com/users/4386/wil)

   [image: top users week of 08-30-2010]
3. Best meta post:

   [how to deal with an answer that is resolved, but not answered?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1463/how-to-deal-with-an-answer-that-is-resolved-but-not-answered) by [**brice**](https://meta.superuser.com/users/25890/brice)
4. Most awesome new question or answer:

   [SSH: Why doesn't "get" command work?](https://superuser.com/questions/188411/ssh-why-doesnt-get-command-work/188433#188433) answer by [**Spiff**](https://superuser.com/users/30792/spiff)

We are contacting the winners now, so be sure to check your email inboxes!

Comment: Congratulations to the winners!

Answer (score 3):

Congrats to the winners :D

[image: close]

Comment: I _tried_ to resist NOT posting the same, but failed miserably :(

Comment: lol, I was wondering what the delay was...